# Find the closest latitude and longitude

Tags: python

I'm writing a small program and to improve efficiency, I need to be able to find the closest latitude and longitude in my array.

Assume you have the following code:

```
tempDataList = [{'lat': 39.7612992 , 'lon': -86.1519681}, 
                {"lat": 39.762241, "lon": -86.158436}, 
                {"lat": 39.7622292, "lon": -86.1578917}]

tempLatList = []
tempLonList = []

for item in tempDataList:
    tempLatList.append(item['lat'])
    tempLonList.append(item['lon'])

closestLatValue = lambda myvalue: min(tempLatList, key=lambda x: abs(x - myvalue))
closestLonValue = lambda myvalue: min(tempLonList, key=lambda x: abs(x - myvalue))

print(closestLatValue(39.7622290), closestLonValue(-86.1519750))
```

The result I get is:

```
(39.7622292, -86.1519681)
```

What it should be is (in this example, the last object in the list)

```
(39.7622292, -86.1578917)
```

I know how to get a single value's closest cell but, I would like to make the lambda function to consider both values but I'm not entirely sure how. Help?

Comment: Use `min` on the original list of dicts - no use in separating it into two lists - and use Pythagoras' theorem in your key function.

Comment: You are correctly getting the lowest longitude value. You are separating out those values. Don't separate out the values, calculate the distance for the latitude and longitude *together*.

Comment: just use euclidean distance -))

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I realize they need to be computed together but I'm not entirely sure how. Can you show me?

Comment: @booky99: see [Getting distance between two points based on latitude/longitude \[python\]](//stackoverflow.com/q/19412462) or [How can I quickly estimate the distance between two (latitude, longitude) points?](//stackoverflow.com/q/15736995)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, this isn't a matter of calculating distance. This is a matter of finding the values closest to the sets found in my original array

Comment: @booky99: yes, and you then need to calculate the distance between your target and each dictionary.

Comment: @marmeladze, can you put that into code?

Comment: sure, wait a minute.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

For a correct calculation of the distance between points on the globe, you need something like the [Haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula. Using the Python implementation offered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21623206/5459839), you could code it like this:

```
from math import cos, asin, sqrt

def distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    p = 0.017453292519943295
    hav = 0.5 - cos((lat2-lat1)*p)/2 + cos(lat1*p)*cos(lat2*p) * (1-cos((lon2-lon1)*p)) / 2
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(hav))

def closest(data, v):
    return min(data, key=lambda p: distance(v['lat'],v['lon'],p['lat'],p['lon']))

tempDataList = [{'lat': 39.7612992, 'lon': -86.1519681}, 
                {'lat': 39.762241,  'lon': -86.158436 }, 
                {'lat': 39.7622292, 'lon': -86.1578917}]

v = {'lat': 39.7622290, 'lon': -86.1519750}
print(closest(tempDataList, v))
```

### Haversine formula

The formula is given on Wikipedia as follows:

```
              1 − cos()  
     hav() = ──────────  
                  2
```

...where  is either the difference in latitude (), or the difference in longitude (). For the actual angle  between two points, the formula is given as:

```
     hav() = hav(₂ − ₁) + cos(₁)cos(₂)hav(₂ − ₁)
```

So that becomes:

```
              1 − cos(₂ − ₁)                 1 − cos(₂ − ₁)
     hav() = ──────────────── + cos(₁)cos(₂)────────────────
                  2                                   2
```

The distance is calculated from that, using this formula (also on Wikipedia):

```
      = 2 arcsin(√hav())
```

In the above script:

- `p` is the factor to convert an angle expressed in degrees to radians: π/180 = 0.017453292519943295...
- `hav` is the haversine calculated using the above formula
- 12742 is the diameter of the earth expressed in km, and is thus the value of 2 in the above formula.

Comment: Goodness gracious great balls of fire. Thats perfect. So fast too. It clocked in at 0.03 MS on an old laptop. thanks!

Comment: Hi any one please mention what is p ,a , float value 0.017453292519943295 with unit and 0.5 with unit in the above answer

Comment: @Jasir, I added a section with some explanations. Let me know if this clarifies it.

Answer (score 3):

Also u can simple do:

```
import mpu
def distance(point1, point2):
    return mpu.haversine_distance(point1, point2)

def closest(data, this_point):
    return min(data, key=lambda x: distance(this_point, x))
```

Comment: Why does somebody disliked this solution? Explain, please what's wrong?

Comment: if you have like 1M points and you have to find closest point from them then this solution will not work. The correct solution is to create a kd-tree or ball-tree using available lat longs and then find closest point

Comment: @abggcv yep, but OP said he writes a *small* program. so this will work for exact this case.

Comment: Well not sure if by *small* OP means the number of lines of code or size of available lat longs. I do not see anything wrong with your code for small number of lat longs.

Comment: @Chiefir probably because you have to pip install an additional module vs doing it with built in math module instead.

Answer (score 0):

if earth is plane,

```
from itertools import combinations
from math import sqrt

coords = [{'lat': 39.7612992 , 'lon': -86.1519681}, 
                {"lat": 39.762241, "lon": -86.158436}, 
                {"lat": 39.7622292, "lon": -86.1578917}]


def euclidean(l1, l2):
    return ((l1[0]**2)-(l2[0]**2)) + ((l1[1]**2)-(l2[1]**2)) 

pairs = [j for j in combinations([i.values() for i in coords], 2)]
pairs.sort(key= lambda x: euclidean(*x))
print pairs[-1]
```

Comment: very slow when coords list is long