# Find closest location between all locations in a list of locations in csv file Python

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, geolocation, location

I have a list of locations in a csv file(which is 13000 points) and I want to find nearest location(in the same file) to each of them. 
I found the answer in 
[Find the closest latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336756/find-the-closest-latitude-and-longitude)
  very helpful but when I try to use a data frame instead of dictionary it shows error.

my code is :

```
from math import cos, asin, sqrt
import os
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('E:\My_Desktop\smart_capex')

sites=pd.read_csv('EXISTING.csv')

def distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    p = 0.017453292519943295
    a = 0.5 - cos((lat2-lat1)*p)/2 + cos(lat1*p)*cos(lat2*p) * (1-cos((lon2-lon1)*p)) / 2
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a))

def closest(data, v):
  return min(data, key=lambda x: 
  distance(v['LATITUDE'],v['LONGTITUDE'],x['LATITUDE'],x['LONGTITUDE']))


tempDataList = sites

v = sites

print(closest(tempDataList, v))
```

but it shows below error:

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: your `v['LATITUDE]` etc are strings and in your `distance()` function you make calculations with these arguments. So you need to parse them to `int()`

Comment: I changed them to float but same error still exists.

Comment: Did you do this: `return min(data, key=lambda x: distance(int(v['LATITUDE']), int(v['LONGTITUDE']), int(x['LATITUDE']), int(x['LONGTITUDE'])))`?

Comment: @KostasCharitidis it returns another error : cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>